# Wait for upload to finish or for success message to pop out

Tags: python, selenium

I have a selenium application that upload multiple files into a web application

on the upload web page you can select up to 4 uploads, that means if I am uploading 8, I have to repeat the step twice to upload 4 on every page

The problem that I am having with selenium is that it just does not slow down, meaning it does not wait for the first 4 files to upload. It starts right away moving around and uploading the other 4 and crashing the web applet.

When I click ok to upload the 4 files I get this processing message:

[image]

And when the upload is done I get this successful message:

[image]

my python code:

```
def upload(driver, fileNum, filePath):
      #if I have more than one file
      if fileNum > 1:     
            #while number of files is not 0 and files being uploaded on one page are 4
            while fileNum > 0 and i < 4:



                  #add file for every select button

                  select_link = driver.find_element_by_name('file_'+str(n))
                  select_link.send_keys(filePath[j])

                  i += 1
                  n += 1
                  j += 1
                  fileNum -= 1

            #check if after uploading the 4 files there are still more files to upload
            #if yes
            if fileNum > 0:
                  #if yes, click ok to upload the first four and call the function again
                  ok_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("borderButton")
                  ok_link.click()

                  #recursive call
                  upload(driver, fileNum, filePath)
            else:
                  #just upload it without calling recursive function
                  ok_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name("borderButton")
                  ok_link.click()
```

As you can see, I call the function `upload(driver, fileNum, filePath)` recursively when the first 4 are uploaded and there are still more files

Is there a way to wait for the first 4 to finish before calling the recursive function ? either by waiting for successful message to pop out or by waiting for processing message to go away ?

How would I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mahsum Akbas had part of the answer. You would want to wait for the `Processing...` popup to appear and then disappear. One way to do this is to

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XX, "Processing... popup locator")))
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XX, "Processing... popup locator")))
```

Comment: thanks. why did u add `popup locator` at the end of the text?

Comment: "Processing... popup locator" is meant to be replaced by the locator for the Processing... message that comes up. You have a picture of it in your question. I don't have the HTML for it so I couldn't put it in myself. A locator is something like `By.id("processingPopupExampleId");`

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to wait for specific jobs to be completed.

1. Using [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) where you can specify the web element to be present before any other process to start.  This is the best way.
2. Using [Implicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#implicit-waits).

In this case specifically ensure that the the html element contains

> File(s) have(s) been uploaded successfully!

is  loaded in the web page.

Answer (score 0):

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XX, "your progress bar selector")))
```

Comment: doesn't this wait for element progress bar to show? I would want to wait for it t disappear until upload is done no?

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.